# How to get video duration for a video present in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, video-intelligence-api

I have uploaded a video to Google's Cloud Storage bucket and referenced their URL in the Video Intelligence API. When I tried to get the video duration of the uploaded video, Video Intelligence API doesn't return anything.

This is the code I used:

```
require "google/cloud/video_intelligence"

video_intelligence_client = Google::Cloud::VideoIntelligence.new
features_element = :LABEL_DETECTION
features = [features_element]

operation = video_intelligence_client.annotate_video input_uri: input_uri, features: features
p "PROCESSING......"
p operation
raise operation.results.message? if operation.error?

operation.wait_until_done!
metadata = operation.metadata
puts metadata
```

Is it possible to get video time duration using Video Intelligence API? Alternatively, how should I get it from Google Cloud Storage API?

Answer (score 0):

1. Video Intelligence API does not calculate video duration. You can check available methods in [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/video%20intelligence/videointelligence/v1/)
2. Google Cloud Storage treats any kind of content the same way (videos, music, zip files, documents, ...) so you have to calculate and store it for example as [custom metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata).
3. If you do not know the duration during upload, you can calculate it in [Cloud Function triggered automatically after upload finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50017636/what-is-the-easiest-method-to-know-the-duration-of-a-video-stored-in-firebase-st).